# Google Map or login working fine in signed apk but same apk published on google play then map or login not working

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I have generated Sh1 key from release keystore file then create api key from sh1 key for release mode then paste the key release folder also have generated debug mode key also in debug folder.Map is working fine in release apk but not after download same apk on google Play.

keytool -list -v -keystore F:\Sanjeev\Location\abc.jks -alias abc

i have generated sh1 from above keytool

Please suggest me what am i doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I understand you're not able to use your app’s original keystore.

Unless you are enrolled in Google Play app signing, the only solution to this issue is to publish a new app with a new package name and a new key. In order to transition existing users to the new app, you’ll need to update the original app’s description with a link to the new app and unpublish the original app.

I absolutely understand this is a significant inconvenience, however, due to security concerns Google does not keep a copy of your keystore and at this time we do not support the deletion of apps or the re-use of package names.

You can read through this article in the Android Studio Help Center for more information about keystores.